# What is the difference between "put back" and "put away"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between *put back* and *put away*? For example:

> After you finish reading, please **put** the books **back**/**away**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put something back, the item is being returned to its original place. I would put a book back onto a shelf.

When you put something away, it might not have previously been in that location. I would put away the groceries that I had just purchased.